# Bhandari Algorithm: Canceling Edges

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, network-flow, weighted-graphs

I have a quick question on implementing the Bhandari algorithm.  I do not have the textbook where the algorithm is originally given (*Bhandari, Ramesh (1999). Survivable networks: algorithms for diverse routing*), and the online resources I've found are a little ambiguous on this point...

Say I want to obtain k disjoint paths.  I run the algorithm k times and get P1, P2, P3, ..., Pk paths.  I then look through these paths and remove edges that 'overlap'.  The ambiguity is once I find an overlap, do I completely neglect that edge, or, do I alternate including it/excluding it based on the number of times the edge is traversed?  i.e) if an edge is travered once: include, twice: exclude, 3 times: include, 4 times: exclude, etc...

One additional question.  Can I run the algorithm k times, and do the edge exclusion once at the very end on all Pk paths, or do I have the modify each path as it is created.  The paper I found (*Iqbal, F. and Kuipers, F. A. 2015. Disjoint Paths in Networks. Wiley Encyclopedia of Electrical and Electronics Engineering. 1–11.*) suggests I need to modify the path edges as I create the paths, but from what I can tell about the algorithm it seems like I can just exclude the edges once at the very end.  Thanks!

Comment: If even you can't find a reference *and* don't give the algorithm, how do you expect us to be able to help you? At the very least, you should tell us which book you found it in; maybe someone has it handy. Please also cite the articles you mention in the proper way.

Comment: Updated to add better references, I figured giving the name of the algorithm would be enough for anyone who was familiar with it.

Comment: I have never heard the name, so it's probably not standard. Given that the book seems to be by the same person and you can't find anything else supports that hypothesis. It may not be a well-known algorithm. Is there a particular reason you want to use that one? Anyway, good luck; maybe someone is intrigued enough to get the book from their library.

Comment: It is supposed to be very similar to Suurballe's algorithm but much easier to implement.  I've got it all coded up, but just need this ambiguity to be resolved.  I'd be open to suggestions on other algorithms, speed and simplicity would definitely be a plus.  Essentially, I am looking for k-disjoint path's through a network (directed).

Comment: Why don't you quote the part you feel is ambiguous?